# Array en Mysql WHERE LIKE? usando explode

Tags: php

Como puedo arreglar mi codigo? necesito que mi buscador pueda encontrar mis posts ingresando un array de palabras pero que lo busque en 3 tablas diferentes que tengo en mi consulta, por ejemplo si pongo 3 palabras que las busque en mi tabla keywords, title o body_value que es el cuerpo del post

```html
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['text'])) {
    $words = explode(" ", $_GET['text']);
    $limit = 40;
    $result = array();

    if (count($words) > 0) {
        $keyword = "'%".$words[0]."%'";

        for($i=1;$i<count($words);$i++){
            $keyword .= " or field_data_field_keywords.field_keywords_value like '%".$words[$i]."%'";
        }

        $body = "'%".$words[0]."%'";

        for($j=1;$j<count($words);$j++){
            $body .= " or field_data_body.body_value like '%".$words[$j]."%'";
        }

        $title = "'%".$words[0]."%'";

        for($k=1;$k<count($words);$k++){
            $title .= " or node.title like '%".$words[$k]."%'";
        }
        $alias = $sql->select_simple("SELECT field_data_field_keywords.entity_id, field_data_field_keywords.field_keywords_value, alias, node.title, field_data_body.body_value, node.status
            FROM field_data_field_keywords
            LEFT JOIN node
            ON field_data_field_keywords.entity_id = node.nid
            LEFT JOIN field_data_body
            ON field_data_body.entity_id = field_data_field_keywords.entity_id
            LEFT JOIN url_alias
            ON source = CONCAT('node/',field_data_field_keywords.entity_id)
            WHERE (field_keywords_value LIKE ".$keyword.")
            OR (body_value LIKE ".$body.")
            OR (title LIKE ".$title.")
            AND (node.status = 1)
            ORDER BY field_data_field_keywords.entity_id DESC
            LIMIT 10 ");

        while (!empty($alias) && $url = mysqli_fetch_assoc($alias)) {
            $temp = file_get_contents($rest . $url['alias']);
            if (!empty($temp)) {
                $temp = json_decode($temp, true);
                unset($temp['articulo'][0]['ads']);
                unset($temp['articulo'][0]['adsTitles']);
                unset($temp['articulo'][0]['body']);
                unset($temp['articulo'][0]['bodyAMP']);
                unset($temp['articulo'][0]['rel']);
                array_push($result, $temp['articulo'][0]);
            }
        }

    }


    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error, o el problema? ¿Imprimiste tus consultas y las revisaste a ver si no tienen error de sintaxis? ¿Las probaste directamente en el manejador de base de datos?

Comment: la consulta esta bien lo que quiero es buscar un array de palabras con explode o implode ya que el buscador debe de funcionar desde esos 3 campos que puse ahi, entonces no funciona bien este codigo

Comment: Cuando tú hablas de *tres campos* a alguien que no conoce tu programa no estás explicando nada. El problema de preguntas planteadas así es que obligas a alguien que quiere ayudarte a tratar de analizar la lógica de tu código para luego ver dónde está el fallo. ¿Por qué no indicas exactamente dónde está el problema, explicando un poco lo que hace el código?

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto solo busco una ayuda ya desesperada porque no me sale como deberia, pero basicamente es un buscador, debe buscar a partir de un array de caracteres me entendes? cual quiera que sean los campos solo necesito que al ingresar que se yo 3 o mas palabras al input de mi pagina analice si es de mi campo titulo o de mi campo body o de mi campo keyword ya?

Comment: es una cadena (string) de palabras separadas por espacios que se convierte en un arreglo (array) y luego queres ver si aparece cada una de esas palabras en cada una de las 3 columnas(campos de la tabla)?

Comment: @aloMalbarez exacto, exacto eso, entonces quiero ver si mi codigo esta bien o no porque no me funciona, la consulta esta bien pero no se si estoy usando bien el explode.

Comment: si, esa parte parece estar bien, el resto yo usaría sentencias preparadas. armando el sql igual pero con parametros, sino es una locura de injections o errores

Comment: @aloMalbarez pues es que lo que quiero usar es el explode bien pues cuando solo uso un for y busco en un campo funciona a la perfeccion pero cuando agrego mas campos y otros for ya no, entonces queria ver si estoy usando bien los for o no son necesariamente 3 o como

Comment: Yo te recomiendo en lugar de hacer un explode de las palabras y hacer like, utilizar el match against, te simplifica mucho la búsqueda y está pensado para hacer búsquedas en lenguaje natural.